# Is a link in CKEditor can pass OsCid?

Tags: php, ckeditor, oscommerce

I am using `CkEditor` in my `osCommerce` site.

Some of the pages use text content edited by `CkEditor` in `admin>tools>page manager>pagename.`

The text editor allows for `HTML` but not `PHP`.

My concern is whether the links on these pages pass session `ID’s`?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the saving of the content on server side, parse all urls and remove session ids.

Comment: That means the links on the CKEditor pages pass session ID's?

Comment: Do you mean when they are displayed? No, you have to do it when they are displayed.

Comment: In Oscommerce tep_href_link() passes session_id.But in CKEditor we use <a href="">. Is this link passes session_id?

Comment: No, it's not, unless session.use_trans_sid is on. You have to do it when they are displayed.